# Extract items in a list using variable names in R

Tags: r, list, variables, extract

I'm parsing a JSON using the RJSONIO package.

The parsed item contains nested lists.

Each item in the list can be extracted using something like this:

```
dat_raw$`12`[[31]]
```

which correctly returns the string stored at this location (in this example, the `'12'` refers to the month and `[[31]]` to day).

```
"31-12-2021"
```

I now want to run a `for` loop to sequentially extract the date for every month. Something like this:

```
for (m in 1:12) {

     print(dat_raw$m[[31]])

}
```

This, naturally, returns a `NULL` because there is no `$m[[31]]` in the list.
Instead, I'd like to extract the objects stored at `` $`1`[[31]] ``, `` $`2`[[31]] ``, ... `` $`12`[[31]] ``.

There must be a relatively easy solution here but I haven't managed to crack it. I'd value some help. Thanks.

EDIT: I've added a screenshot of the list structure I'm trying to extract. The actual JSON object is quite large for a `dput()` output. Hope this helps

[image: dat_raw data structure]

So, to get the date in this list, I'd use something like `` dat_raw$data$`1`[[1]]$date$gregorian$date ``.

What I'm trying to do is run a loop to extract multiple items of the list by cycling through `` $data$`1`[[1]]$... ``, `` $data$`2`[[1]]$... `` ... `` $data$`12`[[1]]$... `` using `$data$m[[1]]$...` in a `for` loop where `m` is the month.

Comment: Can you provide example of `dat_raw` using `dput` ? Have you tried `unlist(dat_raw)` ?

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. I've added a screenshot of the actual list I'm trying to extract data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `` dat_raw$`12`[[31]] ``, you can have `dat_raw[[12]][[31]]` if `12` is the 12th element of the JSON. So your `for` loop would be:

```r
for (m in 1:12) {
     print(dat_raw[[m]][[31]])
}
```