# Obtaining the values of an attribute in a graph, with the attribute name stored in a variable

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to create several functions where the vertex attribute of a graph created with the [R `igraph` package](https://r.igraph.org) is contained in a variable

```
library(igraph)
graph <- make_graph( ~ A-B-C-D-A, E-A:B:C:D,
                      F-G-H-I-F, J-F:G:H:I,
                      K-L-M-N-K, O-K:L:M:N,
                      P-Q-R-S-P, T-P:Q:R:S,
                      B-F, E-J, C-I, L-T, O-T, M-S,
                      C-P, C-L, I-L, I-P)
V(graph)$degree <- degree(graph)
V(graph)$btw <- betweenness(graph)
```

I want then to do something like this:

```
attribute <- "degree"
```

And then obtain a vector with the corresponding vertex attribute. `V(graph)` seems to be a list, so it should be straightforward. However,

```
V(graph)["btw"] # Error in simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) : Unknown vertex selected
V(graph)[attribute] # Same error
```

and there's obviously no way to put a variable behind `$`. I have checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67752023/extract-items-in-a-list-using-variable-names-in-r) but it's not clear to me how to apply it in this case.

Eventually, what I want is not to repeat code when I define a `function(graph, attribute)`, for instance, to create data frames for different defined attributes. Any idea how to proceed in this case?

Comment: `data.frame(name = V(graph)$name, attr = vertex_attr(graph, attribute))` will give data frame with the vertex names and attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

Checking out [the `igraph` manual pages you find `vertex_attr`](https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/vertex_attr.html). Just use

```
vertex_attr(graph, attribute)
```